# Getting a different date on formatting

Tags: php

I am formatting a Date on PHP using the following code:

```
$date = "2014-11-01";
$date_formatted =  gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

When I print them, the formatted date goes a day back. I was quite surprised. I am not simply looking for a solution (there are many for simple stuff like this). ***I would like to know how that happened.***

```
echo $date . " ---> " . $date_formatted;    
//Displays: 2014-11-01 ---> 2014-10-31
```

Comment: Seems ok to me: http://codepad.org/rTXAEHLT

Comment: See this: http://codepad.org/L7YzM3jN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you use `gmdate`. This will give you a date in GMT based on the supplied timestamp.

strtotime will *not* use GMT by default and instead use your local timezone. So when you call `gmdate`, it will reduce the date and time by your timezone offset.

To fix this, use `date` instead of `gmdate` or set your system's timezone to UTC.